# AVG() not accurate in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, average

I am trying to calculate an `Avg()` for an column with where condition using SQL Server Management Studio 2008. When I try the `AVG(column-name)` in a SQL query it gives me a rounded value and not a decimal value.

When I copy the dataset into MS Excel I get the accurate value with 4 decimal (example: 10.74) in SQL I am getting just 10. Any help is appreciated.

My query:

```
SELECT Item, AVG(POOrdrQty) 
FROM [tableWR] 
where Item ='737' AND POOrdrQty <((select AVG([POOrdrQty]) FROM [tableWR]) * 2) 
group by Item
```

Comment: Please show us your query, your data, the output and the desired output.

Comment: SELECT Item, AVG(POOrdrQty) FROM [tableWR]
 where Item ='737' 
  AND POOrdrQty <((select AVG([POOrdrQty]) FROM [tableWR]) * 2) 
 group by Item

Comment: Item (No column name)
737 82

Comment: In the future please add that information to your question.  I went ahead and did it for you this time.

Comment: Abe: Do you mean the SQL?

Comment: Yes, exactly.  You can edit your question to include missing information.  This is usually better than adding it as a comment.

Comment: What data types are your database fields?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The resulting type of the `avg` aggregate is the same type as the value you use as parameter. If the field is an `int`, the result will be rounded to fit the type.

Cast the value that you use as parameter: `avg(cast(column-name as float))`.

Comment: Half an hour of head scratching until I found this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

avg(column_name * 1.0) to convert data type to float