# How to group a dataframe

Tags: r

I have the following data:

```
structure(list(chr = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), leftPos = c(720916L, 736092L, 818159L, 
4105086L, 4140849L, 4164911L, 4464314L, 4764317L, 4906564L, 5010398L, 
5690705L, 5775286L, 5867036L, 7230474L, 9719183L, 9723741L, 10142816L, 
12733035L, 12742872L, 13996088L), Means1 = c(-4.50166373984263, 
22.7414854787421, 76.5674149543741, 49.6843654244713, -6.76800756009397, 
-5.48616887633702, 171.974765532105, -2.8004419462491, 251.238878920906, 
24.3172106993831, 92.07778585458, -9.2775123433234, 110.959507183586, 
-2.57278963951353, 30.5966726830686, -6.67824575085661, 13.9003103772433, 
99.9034503108899, 11.7786055209302, 57.4114695945089), Means2 = c(-4.50166373984263,
39.4695853682122, 128.134808692772, 140.343227472869, 12.2782402432039, 
4.51728744523118, 103.786232453211, 7.2030143753191, 77.4307425703948, 
17.496276591372, 46.8586391096806, -9.2775123433234, 90.4074077805074, 
18.1392689981969, 32.2700556572673, -6.67824575085661, 17.7360779927443, 
72.2607261926, -5.09768550127924, 55.027412413907), Means3 = c(-4.50166373984263, 
46.7166260656872, 102.330672294296, 91.1594353147049, -6.76800756009397, 
7.86681297424078, 134.793892503456, -2.8004419462491, 103.286968070986, 
15.8436793365245, 59.5942459167218, -9.2775123433234, 114.600293200803, 
21.6610650365489, 19.763233485681, -6.67824575085661, 21.3471182295293, 
101.934037199673, -5.09768550127924, 72.3408810065695), Means4 = c(0, 
49.6962372223769, 132.868329968312, 151.140132674376, 19.0462478032979, 
10.0034563215682, 106.841760397079, 10.0034563215682, 88.6977192399028, 
22.252438424421, 49.7002255511708, 0, 106.856532283882, 20.7120586377105, 
34.6415203071056, 0, 20.7120586377105, 75.2943986695856, 0, 58.1026432784387
)), .Names = c("chr", "leftPos", "Means1", "Means2", "Means3", 
"Means4"), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

I would like to group by chr and leftPos, and get a mean of each of the other columns in that group.

I tried the following to do this:

```
CLL <- function (col) {
  col <- as.data.frame(RawZoutliers %>%
                         group_by(chr, binnum = (leftPos) %/% 500000) %>%
                         summarise(Means = mean(Means)) %>%
                         mutate(leftPos = (binnum+1) * 120000) %>%
                         select(leftPos, Means))
}

RawZoutliersBin<-lapply(RawZoutliers, CLL)
```

but it was a failure. The error says:

```
Error during wrapup: no applicable method for 'group_by_' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"
Error during wrapup: target context is not on the stack
Error during wrapup: error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'as.data.frame': target context is not on the stack)
```

I'm not sure how to do this

Comment: Maybe a dupe? http://stackoverflow.com/q/21982987/1191259

Comment: Not a duplicate as I need to group over a certain bin size which the question you've highlighted doesnt do

Comment: Okay. I was starting to formulate a solution, modifying your example. Unfortunately, even if I do `DF %>%
    mutate(binnum = (leftPos) %/% 500000) %>%
    group_by(chr, binnum) %>%
    summarise(Means = mean(Means))`, I get stuck, since you have no `Means` var. Anyway, that's what Cath meant by "create another variable" -- use `mutate` or similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the mean of every column by `chr` and `leftPos` with:

```
aggregate(. ~ chr + leftPos, data=mydata, FUN=mean)
```

In your example data, as your `leftPos` are all distinct, you will get your original data.frame as result.

For example, to get the mean by `chr` of every column, apart from `chr` (including `leftPos`):

```
 aggregate(. ~ chr, data=mydata, FUN=mean)
 # chr leftPos   Means1   Means2   Means3   Means4
#1   1 6372642 48.75335 41.89019 43.90577 47.82846
```

**EDIT**

If you want to do the means by "bins" of `leftPos`, here is a way with `cut`

```
mydata$bin <- cut(mydata$leftPos, breaks=c(seq(min(mydata$leftPos), max(mydata$leftPos), by=500000), max(mydata$leftPos)), include.lowest=T, labels=FALSE)
```

(you don't have to do a call to `cut` by chromosome as you are further subtyping your data also by chromosome).

Changing the last 4 `chr` to 2, you'll get:

```
aggregate(. ~ chr + bin, data=mydata, FUN=mean)
#   chr bin  leftPos     Means1     Means2     Means3    Means4
#1    1   1   758389  31.602412  54.367577  48.181878  60.85486
#2    1   7  4136949  12.476730  52.379585  30.752747  60.06328
#3    1   8  4464314 171.974766 103.786232 134.793893 106.84176
#4    1   9  4893760  90.918549  34.043345  38.776735  40.31787
#5    1  10  5690705  92.077786  46.858639  59.594246  49.70023
#6    1  11  5821161  50.840997  40.564948  52.661390  53.42827
#7    1  14  7230474  -2.572790  18.139269  21.661065  20.71206
#8    1  18  9719183  30.596673  32.270056  19.763233  34.64152
#9    1  19  9723741  -6.678246  -6.678246  -6.678246   0.00000
#10   2  19 10142816  13.900310  17.736078  21.347118  20.71206
#11   2  25 12737954  55.841028  33.581520  48.418176  37.64720
#12   2  27 13996088  57.411470  55.027412  72.340881  58.10264
```

Comment: How can I specify the size of the grouping eg group by every 500000 leftPos? Is this possible with aggregate?

Comment: @SebastianZeki you can create another variable that you'll use for grouping

Comment: can you show me how? Do I create the variable in the original dataframe?

Comment: @SebastianZeki, e.g. (clearly not optimize): `mydata$bin <- cut(mydata$leftPos, breaks=c(seq(min(mydata$leftPos), max(mydata$leftPos), by=500000), max(mydata$leftPos)), include.lowest=T, labels=FALSE)` and then `aggregate(. ~ chr + bin, data=mydata, FUN=mean)`.