# R join same row and calculate mean value

Tags: r, join, dataframe

I have a  data frame that looks like this:

```
data<-data.frame(y=c(1,1,2,2,3,4,5,5),x=c(5,5,10,10,5,10,5,5))

  y  x
1 1  5
2 1  5
3 2 10
4 2 30
5 3  5
6 4 10
7 5  4
8 5  8
```

How can a merge those rows with same value in y column and  modify the x column value to the mean of them.

I would like something like this:

```
  y  x
1 1  5
2 2 20
3 3  5
4 4 10
7 5  6
```

I'm trying:

```
unique(data)
```

But it removes the values instead of doing the mean of same rows.

Comment: The actual dupe should be [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21982987/mean-per-group-in-a-data-frame) I suppose. But who cares, right? No one uses Google anymore anyway.

Comment: @DavidArenburg Why google when the helpful people on SO give you a tailor-made answer in no time anyway?

Answer (score 3):

It is easy with `dplyr`. Like here:

```
library("dplyr")

data %>% 
    group_by(y) %>% 
    summarise(x=mean(x))
```

Comment: Add `y` to summarize for a complete output. i.e. `summarize(y, x=mean(x))`

Comment: @Tal J. Levy, I don't think it's necessary. `y`'s already there.

Comment: It won't be after the summarize.

Comment: I've checked and it is there. It's because `y` is a grouping variable.

Comment: Of course, sorry I forgot about the grouping. You are correct.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `aggregate`

```
aggregate(x~y, data, mean)
```

Answer (score 1):

User plyr.

```
# Create dummy data.
nel = 30
df <- data.frame(x = round(5*runif(nel)), y= round(10*runif(nel)))

# Summarise means
require(plyr)
df$x <- as.factor(df$x)
res <- ddply(df, .(x), summarise, mu=mean(y))
```