# Gather list after partitioning with split in R

Tags: r

Simplified example is:

```
data<-data.frame(rnorm(10),rbinom(10,1,prob=.7))
sdata<-split(data[,1],data[,2])
ret <- lapply(sdata,mean)
```

I make data column and factor column. I come from SQL language and solve an,y task with grouping pattern.

`lapply(sdata,mean)` is:

```
class(ret)
[1] "list"

str(ret)
List of 2
 $ 0: num -0.146
 $ 1: num -0.0572
```

How can I make data frame again from list?

Are there limitation to factor type? Factor become "name" of list elements and I afraid to lose data/precision when convert from name bask to actual data in data frame.

Is there better way to process partitioned/grouped data then split/lapply?

**PS** Fill free to correct question wording. I have little experience with R to write professionally.

**@MLavoie** `ret <- data.frame(lapply(sdata,mean))` gives me:

```
> dim(ret)
[1] 1 2
```

I expect 2x1.

**@David Arenburg** function application in `lapply` on result from  `sapply` receive *not only single column - but all* and *not only single row - but all within group*. This approach may lead to performance degradation but allow any processing logic.

`aggregate` and `data.table` work on individual column in each group if I understand properly.

Comment: ret <- data.frame(lapply(sdata,mean)) ??

Comment: [Yes, there are plenty of ways to calculate mean by group](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21982987/mean-per-group-in-a-data-frame)

Comment: `split` / `lapply` may be sufficient for simple tasks like this, but IMO you are better off getting acquainted with the `data.table` [package](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki) sooner rather than later as it is particularly useful for aggregate operations. And generally speaking you should prefer the `character` class to the `factor` class, with certain exceptions (that don't apply here), e.g. working with statistical models.