# Combine data frame by individuals and find means

Tags: r

I'm new to r so I'm not sure if I'll ask my own question right but I have a data frame from a study and it provided a data set:

[image]

that I trimmed down to what I needed to combine in the picture, I've been trying to find a way to combine each individual(e) and take the mean of each observation(w) so that I'll end up with one row for each individual and the mean of its combined observations. I know how to do this if I do it all separately with

```
mean(m$`30901`$deltaon)
```

(m is the original list) but I wanted to find a way so that it goes

```
mean(m$indivduals[1:40]$deltaon)
```

so that it will give the means for each. I've been trying to mess with for loops but I cant seem to figure it out.

Comment: Please provide the code for your best attempt. Thanks.

Comment: Are we talking [mean by group](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21982987/mean-per-group-in-a-data-frame)?

Answer (score 1):

we can use data.table for this problem:

```
         install.packages("data.table")
         library(data.table)
         m<-data.table(e,w)
         mean(m$individual[1:40]*m$deltaon)
```

think this will help you.

Comment: How are you using data table here?  Once you use `$` it no longer matters that `m` was a data table.