# extract several rows out of a column

Tags: r

I am new to R and this forum. I try to extract several rows out of a column 
and work with them, e.g. calculate the mean of it. I was looking for similar questions but did not find exactly what i wanted. Any help will be highly appreciated. I hope the following lines will show my problem clearly.
First, here is an reproducible example:

```
library(data.table)
counts<-matrix(c(0.3343,0.3543,0.3846,0.3713,0.8341,
0.5764,0.3543,0.8341,0.3846,1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,7,7,7,8,8,8,9,9,9), ncol=3)
colnames(counts) <- c('value','doy','month')
counts2 <- data.table(counts)
counts2[month == 7, list(M1 = mean(value))]
```

This code gives me the mean of month 7. What i want is the mean of the values from month 7 AND 8.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: `aggregate(value~month, counts2[counts2$month %in% c(7, 8)], mean)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mean per group in a data.frame](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21982987/mean-per-group-in-a-data-frame)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that case we use `%in%` to find the aggregated `mean`

```
counts2[month %in% c(7,8), list(M1 = mean(value))]
```

Or if we need it separately, use the `by` option

```
counts2[month %in% c(7,8), list(M1 = mean(value)), by = month]
#   month        M1
#1:     7 0.3577333
#2:     8 0.5939333
```

Comment: Thanks a million! This was exactly what i was looking for :)