# Faster function than aggregate() in R

Tags: r, aggregate

I have the following part of my code:

```
 result <- aggregate(cbind(x1,x2,x3,y1,y2,y3,z1,z2,z3,w)~date, rbind(result, datanew), sum, na.rm=F)
```

Is there a faster way to obtain the same result?
What I wouldlike to do is every time when I have a new data, the new data to be rbinded with the old one and in same time to do the sum per column and row.

For instance:

```
old.data=data.frame(x=c(1:3),y=c(4:6),z=c(7:9),id=c("A","B","B"))
new.data=data.frame(x=c(2:4),y=c(5:7),z=c(8:10),id=c("B","A","A"))
result <- aggregate(cbind(x,y,z)~id, rbind(old.data, new.data), sum, na.rm=F)
```

I am searching for a better solution because this is repeated 100000 times.

Thanks

Comment: Depending on how your loop works, one speed up would be to remove the `rbind` or `cbind` outside of `aggregate` (performing it once) so that the operation is not repeated. `data.table`'s aggregation will probably be faster, especially if the datasets are fairly large.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Im sure the real data is much larger but your solution seems on-point. as some alternatives I benchmarked other approaches:

#### Tidyverse

```
tidy_fn <- function(){
    rbind(old.data, new.data) %>% group_by(id) %>% dplyr::summarise_all(
        function(x)sum(x)
    )
}
```

#### Plyr and base functions (I know..bad-form)

```
plyr_base_fn <- function(){

  plyr::ldply(Map(function(x){
    sapply(x[1:3],sum)
    }, rbind(old.data,new.data) %>% split(., .$id)
    ))

}
```

#### Your aggregation approach:

```
agg_fn <- function(){
    aggregate(cbind(x,y,z)~id, rbind(old.data, new.data), sum, na.rm=F)
}
```

#### Results from two tests:

1000 reps

```
> microbenchmark(tidy_fn(),agg_fn(),plyr_base_fn(),times = 1000L)
Unit: milliseconds
           expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq       max neval
      tidy_fn() 2.220585 2.386112 2.823122 2.529649 2.775300 13.425573  1000
       agg_fn() 1.668601 1.795527 2.149068 1.895666 2.062904 16.117802  1000
 plyr_base_fn() 1.253772 1.331501 1.567777 1.402464 1.526089  8.396307  1000
```

5000 reps

```
microbenchmark(tidy_fn(),agg_fn(),plyr_base_fn(),times = 5000L)
    Unit: milliseconds
               expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq       max neval
          tidy_fn() 2.227752 2.400265 2.696034 2.542617 2.722082  12.46249  5000
           agg_fn() 1.673647 1.792085 2.067232 1.897011 2.019915 301.84694  5000
     plyr_base_fn() 1.247306 1.336010 1.503682 1.411608 1.503290  14.24656  5000
```

Comment: The benchmarks seems misleading... simpler methods will perform better on small data where efficiency doesn't matter. `dplyr` has a lot of infrastructure to help it perform well when performance matters - many rows, may groups. Try benchmarking on data with `5e5` rows and 10k distinct groups and you will see `dplyr` far outperform the others.

Comment: Also not much point in doing 1000s of reps - 100 is usually *plenty* for microbenchmark.

Comment: THANKS FOR YOUR ANSWER

Answer (score 0):

I needed a fast way to calculate the column means of a matrix by group so that the groups are used as rownames in the output matrix, but I ended up using `sapply(split.data.frame(m,v),colMeans)`. When `split.data.frame` is given a matrix as an input, it splits the rows of the matrix by group into a list of matrices:

```
m=matrix(rnorm(1e7),1e3)
v=round(runif(1e3)*1e2)
df=as.data.frame(m)

microbenchmark(times=10,
  split.data.frame=sapply(split.data.frame(m,v),colMeans),
  split.data.frame_for_dataframe=sapply(split.data.frame(df,v),colMeans),
  aggregate={a=aggregate(m,list(v),mean);`rownames<-`(a[,-1],a[,1])},
  split=t(sapply(split(1:nrow(m),v),\(x)colMeans(m[x,,drop=F]))),
  tapply={ncol=ncol(m);o=tapply(asplit(m,1),v,\(x)colMeans(matrix(unlist(x),,ncol)));`rownames<-`(matrix(unlist(o),length(o)),names(o))}
)
```

However the method using `split.data.frame` was about 60 times slower with a dataframe than a matrix:

```
                           expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq        max neval
               split.data.frame   151.1025   152.6566   172.6936   154.4840   197.8200   221.5134    10
 split.data.frame_for_dataframe  9247.5892  9430.0372  9535.6191  9570.4078  9638.5558  9796.0167    10
                      aggregate 10573.4796 10859.2785 10955.4854 11006.6462 11082.8503 11163.1835    10
                          split   157.1666   157.7744   164.2297   159.7609   163.4930   200.6617    10
                         tapply   529.2891   564.2083   614.6336   573.8881   678.4606   800.3653    10
```