# Finding the average for certain unique categories in a data frame

Tags: r, average

If I have an R data frame that looks like this:

```
| Value | TestNum | RepNum |
|:-----:|:-------:|:------:|
| 104   |       1 |      1 |
| 101   |       1 |      2 |
| 101   |       1 |      3 |
| 100   |       2 |      1 |
| 100   |       2 |      2 |
| 100   |       2 |      3 |
| 90    |       3 |      1 |
| 90    |       3 |      2 |
| 90    |       3 |      3 |
| 91    |       4 |      1 |
| 94    |       4 |      2 |
| 94    |       4 |      3 |
| 105   |       5 |      1 |
| 105   |       5 |      2 |
| 108   |       5 |      3 |
```

Is there a way that I can modify this data frame to find the average for the 3 RepNum Values for each unique TestNum so that it looks like this:

```
| Mean | TestNum |
|:----:|:-------:|
| 102  |       1 |
| 100  |       2 |
| 90   |       3 |
| 93   |       4 |
| 106  |       5 |
```

You can create this example data frame in R by copying and pasting this code and executing it.

```
Value<-c(100,101,100,100,100,100,90,90,90,93,94,94,105,105,108)
TestNum<-c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5)
RepNum<-c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3)

df<-data.frame(Value,TestNum,RepNum)
```

**EDIT:** Here's a "more complete" example of the data frame I'm starting with an what I'm hoping to end up with:

```
| FileName | Version |  Category | Value | TestNum | RepNum |
|:--------:|:-------:|:---------:|:-----:|:-------:|:------:|
| File1    | 1.0.1   | Category1 |   104 |       1 |      1 |
| File1    | 1.0.1   | Category1 |   101 |       1 |      2 |
| File1    | 1.0.1   | Category1 |   101 |       1 |      3 |
| File1    | 1.0.2   | Category1 |   100 |       2 |      1 |
| File1    | 1.0.2   | Category1 |   100 |       2 |      2 |
| File1    | 1.0.2   | Category1 |   100 |       2 |      3 |
| File1    | 1.0.4   | Category1 |    90 |       3 |      1 |
| File1    | 1.0.4   | Category1 |    90 |       3 |      2 |
| File1    | 1.0.4   | Category1 |    90 |       3 |      3 |
| File1    | 1.0.5   | Category1 |    94 |       4 |      1 |
| File1    | 1.0.5   | Category1 |    91 |       4 |      2 |
| File1    | 1.0.5   | Category1 |    94 |       4 |      3 |
| File1    | 1.0.8   | Category1 |   105 |       5 |      1 |
| File1    | 1.0.8   | Category1 |   105 |       5 |      2 |
| File1    | 1.0.8   | Category1 |   108 |       5 |      3 |
```

And ending with this:

```
| FileName | Version |  Category | Mean_Value | TestNum |
|:--------:|:-------:|:---------:|:----------:|:-------:|
| File1    | 1.0.1   | Category1 |        102 |       1 |
| File1    | 1.0.2   | Category1 |        100 |       2 |
| File1    | 1.0.4   | Category1 |         90 |       3 |
| File1    | 1.0.5   | Category1 |         93 |       4 |
| File1    | 1.0.8   | Category1 |        106 |       5 |
```

As you've probably noticed, there is only 1 unique entry for both the `FileName` column and the `Category` column. The `Version` column is changing along with the `TestNum` column. So it seems like it might be easiest to simply add in these other columns after I've found the mean.

In the "full" code that I'm working on, I'm getting the mean values for several different files and many unique categories but I've been creating multiple data frames that are created by subsetting an original data frame  on the FileName and Category (and an additional "Case" column).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mean per group in a data.frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21982987/mean-per-group-in-a-data-frame)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `aggregate`

```
aggregate(x = df$Value, by = list(df$TestNum), FUN = mean)
#  Group.1         x
#1       1 100.33333
#2       2 100.00000
#3       3  90.00000
#4       4  93.66667
#5       5 106.00000
```

You could also `split` based on unique values of `TestNum` first and then summarize

```
data.frame(test_num = unique(df$TestNum), mean_value = sapply(split(df$Value, df$TestNum), mean))
#  test_num mean_value
#1        1  100.33333
#2        2  100.00000
#3        3   90.00000
#4        4   93.66667
#5        5  106.00000
```

Comment: Thanks! This works perfectly for the example I gave. One thing I noticed though is that if I extrapolate it to a data frame with more columns than the example data frame had, it leaves me with the Column in the "by" parameter and the mean of the x column. Is there a way that I can use the aggregate function to more or less "collapse" an existing data frame so that it retains other data (it's all repeating for each TestNum) and replaces the Value column with the new "Mean" column? (And drops the RepNum column of course)

Comment: I can add an edit with a table to show what I mean if that wasn't clear. (I felt like it wasn't clear lol)

Comment: sort of. However, the more I think about it, the more I think it will be easier to actually just "restructure" the resulting data frame because I don't think what I was thinking about makes logical sense to do in R. I'll throw an edit in the original example just in case there is an easy way to do it that someone out there knows how to do.

Comment: I got an error: `Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions` And `In split.default(df[,c(1,3)], df$TestNum) : data length is not a multiple of split variable`

Answer (score 1):

Also with `data.table` and `dplyr`, you can do

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, mean(Value), by = TestNum]

library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(TestNum) %>% summarise(mean(Value))
```

If there are other columns, you can use the other columns' first value in each `TestNum`. Like this:

```
df2<-data.frame(FileName = "File1", 
                Version = paste0("1.0.", rep(c(1,2,4,5,8), each = 3)),
                Value, TestNum, RepNum)


## data.table 
keep_cols <- c("FileName", "Version")
setDT(df2)[, c(lapply(.SD, function(x) x[1]), mean_Value = mean(Value)), 
           by = TestNum, .SDcols = keep_cols]

## dplyr
df2 %>% group_by(TestNum) %>% summarise(FileName = FileName[1], 
                                        Version = Version[1], 
                                        mean_Value = mean(Value))
```

Comment: You should take a look at the comment I left on d.b's answer. Because I think the `data.table` method of doing this is the cleanest and simplest way to do it but I had a caveat I put in the comments.

Comment: I'm not calculating additional columns. See my edit in the question for better detail.

Comment: When I tried this, I got back 98 for every entry in the `mean_Values` column. It looks like it took the average of all the values. (For the "data.table" method).

It looks like your "dplyr" method works however.

Comment: Also, would it not be better to create the "Version" column using a vector created like `Versions<-unique(df$Version)`? This way it is easier than having to continually update that parameter.