# Calculate the mean of the remaining rows in table by group

Tags: r, moving-average

I am trying to get the average performance for the all following rows in each group. The grouping factor is **ID** and the variable to be averaged is **performance**. The data is already ordered by the variable **day**.

Desired output example:
For ID A on Day 5 the mean would be 8.25[(9+6+10+8)/4].
For ID A on Day 6 the mean would be 8[(6+10+8)/3]. 
So basically the mean of the remaining performance scores ordered by the day variable.

I am looking to do this in R and currently have failed as the roll_mean function creates NA's as it meets the end of each group.

Any help much appreciated, thanks!

```
structure(list(ID = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
                  "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", 
                  "C", "C", "C", "C", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D"), 
           Day = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 
                   10, 11, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8), 
           Performance = c(5, 
                           3, 3, 6, 9, 6, 10, 8, 10, 9, 2, 5, 8, 4, 6, 3, 6, 3, 2, 4, 
                           4, 9, 10, 10, 3, 4, 2, 9, 4, 7, 4, 9, 6)), 
      .Names = c("ID", 
                 "Day", "Performance"), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
                 ), 
      row.names = c(NA, -33L))
```

Comment: What is the expected output? - Why do you need a rolling mean?

Comment: This is a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21982987/mean-per-group-in-a-data-frame

Comment: Please clarify what do you mean by "the mean of remaining rows"? If you are talking about a moving average, what would the the size of the moving window?

Comment: For example: for **ID A** on **Day 5** the mean would be 8.25[(9+6+10+8)/4].For **ID A** on **Day 6** the mean would be 8[(6+10+8)/3]. So basically the mean of the remaining performance scores ordered by the day variable.