# Finding mean, minimum and maximum of grouped values in data set

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data set where I'm trying to find the mean, minimum and maximum mass of each gang, and my code is as follows:

```
 mass <- Gangs$Mass_kg
 mass.summary <- ddply(Gangs, ~Gang_affiliation, summarise,
  minimum = min(mass),
  mean = mean(mass),
  maximum = max(mass))
```

It outputs as:

```
   Gang_affiliation     minimum mean maximum
    18th Street          86      92   114
    Aryan Brotherhood    86      92   114      
    Black Guerillas      86      92   114
```

But what I really want is for every affiliation to have their own result.

```
   Gang_affiliation     minimum mean maximum
    18th Street          86      92   114
    Aryan Brotherhood    84      98   121      
    Black Guerillas      87      95   127
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Can you please add a reproducible example?

Comment: @smanski I edited my original post to include my inteded outcome

Comment: Why have you done this step ? `mass <- Gangs$Mass_kg` ? Replace `mass` with `Mass_kg` in your attempt or in the answer by @smanski below.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve this by

```
library(dplyr)
Gangs %>% group_by(Gang_affiliation) %>% summarise(minimum = min(mass),
                                                  mean = mean(mass)
                                                  maximum = max(mass))
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: It returns with "Error in UseMethod("group_by_") : 
  no applicable method for 'group_by_' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"

Comment: Is your dataset `Gangs`?  Be sure to see my edit to my answer.

Comment: My data set is `Gangs` but now it has returned to my original post; all the results are duplicated

Comment: Note that is question is a duplicate of [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21982987/mean-per-group-in-a-data-frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21982987/mean-per-group-in-a-data-frame)

Comment: Thanks. Any tips for using multiple functions in `aggregate()`? edit: Looks like its `list(FUN1, FUN2)`?