# Calculating mean score

Tags: mean

I have a dataset that contains a number of different of Subject IDs. They are each part of a specific Chain and were assigned a Generation number in an experiment. I have the mean StructureScore (how much a language is structured) for each participant, but I also want to see what the mean StructureScore is for each generation.

For example, Generation 7 of Chain E exists 4 times, so I want to have the mean score for those 4 participants. I'm not sure how to make a new dataset of just those mean StructureScores? Any suggestion is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: What language is this for? Is there any syntax behind this data?

Comment: I can give you a general solution, but you would have to transfer it to your language to make it work.

Comment: Yes, the compositionality is based on how much the form of the label predicts the meaning so there are some other functions to compute that. Is the syntax important? (In R, btw)

Comment: Ah okay, any suggestion is appreciated!

Comment: I just wanted to know the variable names so I could think through it easier.

Comment: Thanks for that. I can post the syntax, but I was wondering if there is an easy way to compute the mean structure scores for each generation. It's just for plotting the mean values along with the actual values per participant.

Comment: Yeah there is! Here let me post it

Comment: I posted an answer is that what you needed?

Comment: Yes, exactly what I need! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out!

This type of operation is exactly what aggregate was designed for:

[Mean per group in a data.frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21982987/mean-per-group-in-a-data-frame)