# Easy data tidying hacks for codes like these?

Tags: r

I have been repeating these lines of code consistently for smaller data from larger sets of data. My time is effectively taken up trying to reproduce these codes, are there more efficient ways of doing this without such a long process? Also, what are some general rules to keep in mind to avoid repeating this?

Here's an example of many lines of code I use frequently to extract data I need from larger data-sets.
It was as simple as extracting bird species from a larger data-set, placing them into a vector length that matches years and then reproducing means of the population index over these years for all species.

Are there 'hacks' as you may call it, that allow for such a scenario and those similar to be represented in smaller lines of codes, by using more efficient functions? can any examples be given?

```
dat <- read.csv("Bird_Dataset_2019.csv")
  L_starling <- dat[dat$Species=="Starling",]
  L_skylark <- dat[dat$Species=="Skylark",]
  L_yellow_wagtail <- dat[dat$Species=="Yellow Wagtail",]
  L_kestrel <- dat[dat$Species=="Kestrel",]
  L_yellowhammer <- dat[dat$Species=="Yellowhammer",]
  L_greenfinch <- dat[dat$Species=="Greenfinch",]
  L_swallow <- dat[dat$Species=="Swallow",]
  L_lapwing <- dat[dat$Species=="Lapwing",]
  L_housemartin <- dat[dat$Species=="House Martin",]
  L_linnet <- dat[dat$Species=="Linnet",]
  L_greypartridge <- dat[dat$Species=="Grey Partridge",]
  L_turteldove <- dat[dat$Species=="Turtle Dove",]
  L_cornbunting <- dat[dat$Species=="Corn Bunting",]
  L_bullfinch <- dat[dat$Species=="Bullfinch",]
  L_songthrush <- dat[dat$Species=="Song Thrush",]
  L_blackbird <- dat[dat$Species=="Blackbird",]
  L_dunnock <- dat[dat$Species=="Dunnock",]
  #code for population size and farmland occupants in years--------
  years <- 1994:2013
  starling_means <- vector(length = length(years))
  skylark_means <- vector(length = length(years))
  yellow_wagtail_means <- vector(length = length(years))
  kestrel_means <- vector(length = length(years))
  yellowhammer_means <- vector(length = length(years))
  greenfinch_means <- vector(length = length(years))
  swallow_means <- vector(length = length(years))
  lapwing_means <- vector(length = length(years))
  housemartin_means <- vector(length = length(years))
  linnet_means <- vector(length = length(years))
  greypartridge_means <- vector(length = length(years))
  turtledove_means <- vector(length = length(years))
  cornbunting_means <- vector(length = length(years))
  bullfinch_means <- vector(length = length(years))
  songthrush_means <- vector(length = length(years))
  blackbird_means <- vector(length = length(years))
  dunnock_means <- vector(length = length(years))
  #---------------------------------------------------
   for(i in 1:length(years)){
    starling_means[i] <- mean(L_starling$Pop_Index[L_starling$Year==years[i]], na.rm = TRUE)
    skylark_means[i] <- mean(L_skylark$Pop_Index[L_skylark$Year==years[i]], na.rm = TRUE)
    yellow_wagtail_means[i] <- mean(L_yellow_wagtail$Pop_Index[L_yellow_wagtail$Year==years[i]], na.rm = TRUE)
    kestrel_means[i] <- mean(L_kestrel$Pop_Index[L_kestrel$Year==years[i]], na.rm = TRUE)
    yellowhammer_means[i] <- mean(L_yellowhammer$Pop_Index[L_yellowhammer$Year==years[i]], na.rm = TRUE)
    greenfinch_means[i] <- mean(L_greenfinch$Pop_Index[L_greenfinch$Year==years[i]], na.rm = TRUE)
    swallow_means[i] <- mean(L_swallow$Pop_Index[L_swallow$Year==years[i]], na.rum = TRUE)
    lapwing_means[i] <- mean(L_lapwing$Pop_Index[L_lapwing$Year==years[i]], na.rm = TRUE)
    housemartin_means[i] <- mean(L_housemartin$Pop_Index[L_housemartin$Year==years[i]], na.rm = TRUE)
    linnet_means[i] <- mean(L_linnet$Pop_Index[L_linnet$Year==years[i]], na.rm = TRUE)
    greypartridge_means[i] <- mean(L_greypartridge$Pop_Index[L_greypartridge$Year==years[i]], na.rm = TRUE)
    turtledove_means[i] <- mean(L_turteldove$Pop_Index[L_turteldove$Year==years[i]], na.rm = TRUE)
    cornbunting_means[i] <- mean(L_cornbunting$Pop_Index[L_cornbunting$Year==years[i]], na.rm = TRUE)
    bullfinch_means[i] <- mean(L_bullfinch$Pop_Index[L_bullfinch$Year==years[i]], na.rm = TRUE)
    songthrush_means[i] <- mean(L_songthrush$Pop_Index[L_songthrush$Year==years[i]], na.rm = TRUE)
    blackbird_means[i] <- mean(L_blackbird$Pop_Index[L_blackbird$Year==years[i]], na.rm = TRUE)
    dunnock_means[i] <- mean(L_dunnock$Pop_Index[L_dunnock$Year==years[i]], na.rm = TRUE)
  }

  # All means placed into a data.frame-----------------------------
  L_population_frame <- data.frame(years, log(starling_means), log(skylark_means), yellow_wagtail_means, kestrel_means, yellowhammer_means, log(greenfinch_means), log(swallow_means), lapwing_means, housemartin_means, linnet_means, greypartridge_means, turtledove_means, cornbunting_means, bullfinch_means, songthrush_means, log(blackbird_means), dunnock_means)
 colnames(L_population_frame) <- c("Years", "Starling", "Skylark", "YellowWagtail", "Kestrel", "Yellowhammer", "Greenfinch", "Swallow", "Lapwing", "Housemartin", "Linnet", "GreyPartridge", "TurtleDove", "Cornbunting", "Bullfinch", "Songthrush", "Blackbird", "Dunnock")
```

Comment: Probably you are trying to calculate mean by group. Try `aggregate(Pop_Index~ Species + Year, dat, mean)`

Comment: You can use functional programming tools to avoid repetition. For exampple, the task of extracting data would be coded  like this for `mtcars`: `car_list <- lapply(car_names, function(x) mtcars[rownames(mtcars) == x,])`.

Comment: @RonakShah Can this be used to select a specific species such that Species$Blackbird?

Comment: yes, subset it first `aggregate(Pop_Index~ Species + Year, dat[dat$Species == "Blackbird", ], mean)`

Comment: A rule of thumb: as soon as you have the same code more than once and just change object/variable names, you should/can wrap it into a function.

Comment: To add to Ronak Shah, there's also a subset argument in ```aggregate(Pop_Index~ Species + Year, data = dat, subset = Species == 'Blackbird', mean)``` which is a different method of doing what he did

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in comments you can reduce your code by using `aggregate`

```
aggregate(Pop_Index~ Species + Year, dat, mean)
```

to get `mean` `Pop_Index` for each `Year` and `Species`.

There are various way to solve it as shown in [Mean per group in a data.frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21982987/mean-per-group-in-a-data-frame)

To get `mean` for specific subset we can do

```
aggregate(Pop_Index~ Species + Year, dat[dat$Species == "Blackbird", ], mean)
```

Comment: I have found that replacing ```==``` with the logical operator ```%in%``` allows for more objects when combined with ```c()``` .I experienced the problem that ```==``` only allowed up to three objects when combined with ```c()```. Just something I learnt.