# Compute the means and standard deviations of var1 within each level of var2

Tags: r, mean

I have a data set where the variable `Tier` can be 1, 2, 3 , or 4. I need to find the mean of `Full.time` for each type of `Tier`. Here is my code:

```
mean(my_data$Full.time ~ my_data$Tier)
```

and here is my error message:

```
[1] NA
Warning message:
In mean.default(my_data$Full.time ~ my_data$Tier) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

(I also have to do the same thing with standard deviation but I assume the correct answer will be the same with `sd()` instead of `mean()`)

Here is the file:

[image: Text File]

Comment: The answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21982987/mean-per-group-in-a-data-frame) are a terrific summary of the options available for getting means by group.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mean per group in a data.frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21982987/mean-per-group-in-a-data-frame)

Comment: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on making an R question that folks can help with. That includes a sample of data, all necessary code, and a clear explanation of what you're trying to do and what hasn't worked. That said, I don't think I've seen `mean` called on a formula...where did you get that?

Comment: @A.S.K. I don't think so? This is what my textfile looks like

Comment: @A.S.K. I'll edit the post and add the text file

Comment: Try `aggregate(my_data$Full.time, list(my_data$Tier), mean)`; that should create the summary you're looking for.

Comment: Probably because Tier 4 contains NAs somewhere; try `aggregate(my_data$Full.time, list(my_data$Tier), mean, na.rm = T)`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the following code can make things you want:

- if you want compact result of mean and standard deviation, you can use `aggreate()`, i.e.,

```
Mean <- aggregate(Full.time ~ Tier, my_data, mean)
```

and

```
SD <- aggregate(Full.time ~ Tier, my_data, sd)
```

- if you want results of mean and standard deviation with the same rows of `my_data`, you can use `ave()`, i.e.,

```
Mean <- with(my_data, ave(Full.time, Tier, mean))
```

and

```
SD <- with(my_data, ave(Full.time, Tier, sd))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the `dplyr` approach:

```
library(dplyr)

mtcars %>%
    group_by(Tier) %>%
    summarize(mean=mean(Full.time), sd=sd(Full.time))
```

Note that dplyr allows us to name each aggregation result column.
And here's an illustration on `mtcars`, because we can't access your dataset:

```
data(mtcars)

mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% summarize(mean_hp=mean(hp), sd_hp=sd(hp))

    cyl mean_hp sd_hp
  <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>
1     4    82.6  20.9
2     6   122.   24.3
3     8   209.   51.0
```