# Summarize a Variable by All But Group

Tags: r, dplyr, summarize

I have a data.frame and I need to calculate the mean per "anti-group" (i.e. per Name, below).

```
Name     Month  Rate1     Rate2
Aira       1      12        23
Aira       2      18        73
Aira       3      19        45
Ben        1      53        19
Ben        2      22        87
Ben        3      19        45
Cat        1      22        87
Cat        2      67        43
Cat        3      45        32
```

My desired output is like below, where the values for Rate1 and Rate2 are the means of the column's values not found in each group. Please disregard the value, I have made it up for the example. I'd prefer to do this using **dplyr** if possible.

```
Name    Rate1   Rate2
Aira    38      52.2
Ben     30.5    50.5
Cat     23.8    48.7
```

Any help much appreciated! Thank you!

PS - Thanks to **Ianthe** for copying their question and their question's data but changing the question slightly. ([Mean per group in a data.frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21982987/mean-per-group-in-a-data-frame))

Comment: what did you try? You are tagging `dplyr` so did you try `summarise_all`, `summarise_at`, etc...?

Comment: Please make an earnest attempt so we can help with implementation and helps your learning curve.

Comment: Well if I wanted per group, I could easily do the following:
`df %>%
  group_by(Name) %>%
  summarize(Rate1=mean(Rate1), Rate2=mean(Rate2))`
but that calculates the mean of the Rate columns by group. I want to calculate the mean of the rate columns by everything **but** the group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option could be:

```
df %>%
 mutate_at(vars(Rate1, Rate2), list(sum = ~ sum(.))) %>%
 mutate(rows = n()) %>%
 group_by(Name) %>%
 summarise(Rate1 = first((Rate1_sum - sum(Rate1))/(rows-n())),
           Rate2 = first((Rate2_sum - sum(Rate2))/(rows-n())))

  Name  Rate1 Rate2
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 Aira   38    52.2
2 Ben    30.5  50.5
3 Cat    23.8  48.7
```

Or in a less tidy form:

```
df %>%
 group_by(Name) %>%
 summarise(Rate1 = first((sum(df$Rate1) - sum(Rate1))/(nrow(df)-n())),
           Rate2 = first((sum(df$Rate2) - sum(Rate2))/(nrow(df)-n())))
```

Comment: Thanks! I think your solution is cleanest and most generalize-able. Thanks again.

Comment: It could be slightly problematic when NAs are present, but it could be adjusted :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is another idea via base R,

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(unique(df$Name), function(i)colMeans(df[!df$Name %in% i,-c(1:2)])))

#        Rate1    Rate2
#[1,] 38.00000 52.16667
#[2,] 30.50000 50.50000
#[3,] 23.83333 48.66667
```

or complete with `Name`,

```
cbind.data.frame(Name = unique(df$Name), res1)

#  Name    Rate1    Rate2
#1 Aira 38.00000 52.16667
#2  Ben 30.50000 50.50000
#3  Cat 23.83333 48.66667
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyverse)

# exampel dataset
df = read.table(text = "
Name     Month  Rate1     Rate2
Aira       1      12        23
Aira       2      18        73
Aira       3      19        45
Ben        1      53        19
Ben        2      22        87
Ben        3      19        45
Cat        1      22        87
Cat        2      67        43
Cat        3      45        32
", header=T, stringsAsFactors=F)

# function that returns means of Rates after excluding a given name
AntiGroupMean = function(x) { df %>% filter(Name != x) %>% summarise_at(vars(matches("Rate")), mean) }

df %>%
  distinct(Name) %>%                         # for each name
  mutate(v = map(Name, AntiGroupMean)) %>%   # apply the function
  unnest(v)                                  # unnest results

# # A tibble: 3 x 3
#   Name  Rate1 Rate2
#   <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 Aira   38    52.2
# 2 Ben    30.5  50.5
# 3 Cat    23.8  48.7
```

Answer (score 1):

You could compute this as a mean of the group means, weighted by the number of observations in each group, but with the given row's weight equal to 0.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(Name) %>% 
  summarise(n = n(), Rate1 = mean(Rate1), Rate2 = mean(Rate2)) %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(starts_with('Rate')),  ~
    sapply(Name, function(x) weighted.mean(.x, n*(Name != x))))

# A tibble: 3 x 4
  Name      n Rate1 Rate2
  <chr> <int> <dbl> <dbl>
1 Aira      3  38    52.2
2 Ben       3  30.5  50.5
3 Cat       3  23.8  48.7
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
map_dfr(unique(df1$Name), ~ 
   anti_join(df1, tibble(Name = .x)) %>% 
   summarise_at(vars(starts_with('Rate')), mean) %>%
   mutate(Name = .x)) %>%
   select(Name, everything())
#    Name    Rate1    Rate2
#1 Aira 38.00000 52.16667
#2  Ben 30.50000 50.50000
#3  Cat 23.83333 48.66667
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Name = c("Aira", "Aira", "Aira", "Ben", "Ben", 
"Ben", "Cat", "Cat", "Cat"), Month = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 2L, 3L), Rate1 = c(12L, 18L, 19L, 53L, 22L, 19L, 22L, 67L, 
45L), Rate2 = c(23L, 73L, 45L, 19L, 87L, 45L, 87L, 43L, 32L)), 
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

Comment: Sorry, the tibble this code creates doesn't match my desired solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate_at(
    vars(contains('Rate')),
    ~ sapply(1:n(), function(x) mean(.[Name %in% setdiff(unique(df$Name), Name[x])], na.rm = TRUE)
             )
  ) %>%
  distinct_at(vars(-Month))
```

Output:

```
  Name    Rate1    Rate2
1 Aira 38.00000 52.16667
2  Ben 30.50000 50.50000
3  Cat 23.83333 48.66667
```

(Though you are likely much better off with other solutions as `sapply` through rows would be REALLY slow on larger datasets)