# Calculating mean age by group in R

Tags: r, average, mean

I have the following data: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fivethirtyeight/data/master/congress-age/congress-terms.csv

I'm trying to determine how to calculate the mean age of members of Congress by year (termstart) for each party (Republican and Democrat).

I was hoping for some help on how to go about doing this. I am a beginner in R and I'm just playing around with the data.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried answers from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21982987/mean-per-group-in-a-data-frame or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11562656/calculate-the-mean-by-group ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach. Make a filter for the required parties and then summarise. After that you can reshape to wide in order to have both parties for each individual date. Here the code using `tidyverse` functions:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
#Data
df <- read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fivethirtyeight/data/master/congress-age/congress-terms.csv',stringsAsFactors = F)
#Code
newdf <- df %>% filter(party %in% c('R','D')) %>%
  group_by(termstart,party) %>% summarise(MeanAge=mean(age,na.rm=T)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = party,values_from=MeanAge)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 34 x 3
# Groups:   termstart [34]
   termstart      D     R
   <chr>      <dbl> <dbl>
 1 1947-01-03  52.0  53.0
 2 1949-01-03  51.4  54.6
 3 1951-01-03  52.3  54.3
 4 1953-01-03  52.3  54.1
 5 1955-01-05  52.3  54.7
 6 1957-01-03  53.2  55.4
 7 1959-01-07  52.4  54.7
 8 1961-01-03  53.4  53.9
 9 1963-01-09  53.3  52.6
10 1965-01-04  52.3  52.2
# ... with 24 more rows
```