# How to create a mean of a dataframe column with a condition in another column?

Tags: r, dataframe, mean

I have a data frame:

```
head(cat1)

expl.val  pred.val
    1     0.602
    1     0.602
    1     0.602
    1     0.602
    1     0.604
    1     0.604
```

I want to calculate the mean of the pred.val for the different expl.val, which are values from 1 to 14. And put it in a new data frame.

Something like this:

```
expl.val  pred.val
    1     mean of expl.val(1)
    2     mean of expl.val(2)
    3     mean of expl.val(3)
    4     mean of expl.val(4)
    5     mean of expl.val(5)
    6     mean of expl.val(6)
```

How can I do this?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21982987

Comment: or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11562656 ...